# How to post data into a laravel controller method using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

My purpose is :

1. Getting clicked button's id
2. Post this id number to a controller's method.

Note that my routes are working nice. But when i try to pass data, i am having problems.

Here is jQuery :

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "myRouteURL",
            data: (jQuery(this).attr("id"))
        });
```

Here is my controller's method :

```
public function somethingSpecial($passedData){
   DB::table('myTableName')->where('fieldName', '=', $passedData)->delete();
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use only $ or Jquery don't use both in your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's $passedData value.
Why don't you try sending your id with a name, that way you can get it later in your code.
Here's an example:

jQuery:

```
$.ajax( {
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'myRouteURL',
    data : { id : this.id }
} );
```

Controller's method:

```
public function somethingSpecial()
{
    $id = Input::get( 'id' );
    // you probably want to validate this value...
    DB::table( 'myTableName' )->where('fieldName', '=', $id )->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you POST it to a certain route, then just add a post method in your routing. Then define that method in the controller.
Hope this helps.